# Cannot add children to a Grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, grid, viewmodel

There are two ways that I tried to add children to a Grid. One is working but it is not prefered to me because I have ViewModel class. And I want to apply it in that class. So the another way is not working correctly, actually, it is not added as children to Grid. The last way is applied in ViewModel class. Here is two ways that I applided:

**1- Working way.**

```
public LaserLib fiber1 = new LaserLib();
private void MarkInit()
{
     fiber1.Init();   // that is my specialized laser library.
     myGrid.Children.Add(fiber1); // when I do this, I can see the fiber1 condition in grid.
}
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
   MarkInit();
}
```

But, I have many of this and I want to appy to my viewModel.
What I tried:

**2- Not worked. Way 1:**

```
public class ViewModels
{
   public ObservableCollection<MarkingManualStatuses> markingManualStatuses { get; set;} 
          = new ObservableCollection<MarkingManualStatuses(Enumerable.Range(0,4).Select(i => new MarkingManualStatuses()));        
}
    
public class MarkingManualStatuses : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public LaserLib Tmc { get; set; }
    public void TmcInitialize()
    {
         Tmc = new LaserLib ();
         Tmc.Init();
    }
}
```

> I run TmcInitialize() function at MainWindow_Onloaded

Everything is fine for now. My LaserLib gets initialize. it works. But, I cannot add it to grid.
Here is where I tried to add at **ManualPage**:

```
private void listViewMarkingInfos_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     TmcViewerGrid.Children.Clear();
    
     int index = listViewMarkingInfos.SelectedIndex;
     ContainerMarkingDockPanel.DataContext = viewModels.markingManualStatuses[index];
    
     TmcViewerGrid.Children.Add(viewModels.markingManualStatuses[index].Tmc); // this is not working
    
     ContainerMarkingDockPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

**3. Not worked. Way 2:**

I have added

> Grid property

in

> MarkingManualStatuses

It sounds bad but anyway, I just wanted to see if it works or not.

*In viewModel:*

```
public class MarkingManualStatuses : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public LaserLib Tmc { get; set; }
    public Grid myGrid {get;set;}
    public void TmcInitialize()
    {
         Tmc = new LaserLib ();
         Tmc.Init();
         
         myGrid = new Grid();
         myGrid.Children.Add(Tmc);
    }
}
```

*In Manual_Page:*

```
private void listViewMarkingInfos_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     TmcViewerGrid.Children.Clear();
    
     int index = listViewMarkingInfos.SelectedIndex;
     ContainerMarkingDockPanel.DataContext = viewModels.markingManualStatuses[index];
    
     TmcViewerGrid = viewModels.markingManualStatuses[index].myGrid; // this is also not working.
    
     ContainerMarkingDockPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

I have tried two ways but it didn't work. Any suggestions to solve this?
And maybe I missed a small point that I forget, I am not sure, but Thank you all.

Comment: Is `LaserLib` a `CustomControl` or a `UserControl` or somesuch? And I assume you're talking about a standard layout control `Grid`?

Comment: Why would you add an element to a `Grid` in a view model or anywhere else than in the view? It makes no sense at all and breaks what the MVVM pattern is all about. Your `MarkingManualStatuses` class is not a valid view model.

Comment: @Pseudonymous , its a class that communication with laser .dll's.

Comment: @mm8 , As I wrote above, I have laser marking system in my project, also I have see their reaction. In this way, I can get their reactions to grid. (its kind of 2D view). I only can get them to grid. If you have any idea to get this, I am open for recommendation. Also, Why is it not a valid view model? what is your suggestion?

Comment: Because it contains a `Grid` and a `LaserLib` control. It's unclear what you want to do in the view model. Clearly not working woth controls.

Comment: The last way is not clear I know that. it was just for testing. Of course I am not going to use it. It was just for testing.
And LaserLib is necessary to use. I need to use LaserLib class for each one.